# Last survivors on Earth care for embryos and children. Told from little girl's perspective

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I read an old novel when I was in high school. It was about a time after humans had been wiped out somehow. Some survivors lived on Earth, had some human embryos and cared for 2 children.

The story is told by the little girl. Eventually the children meet without the aliens knowing and go outside.

Comment: Unfortunately, when *you* were in high school doesn't help us much.  When was that?  Last year?  Last decade?  Fifty years ago?  Please specify in a more absolute manner (e.g. around 2003 or 1996-8).  You may also want to read over [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337)